# Could not establish a secure connection. Facebook Authentication Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, facebook-authentication, info.plist

I followed all the documentation to add Authentication to my Mobile App with Azure backend (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#register-your-app-for-authentication-and-configure-app-services )

I'm using facebook as a provider to authenticate. The Android project seems to be working as the log in redirects to the facebook log in page, but the iOS project prompts "Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server".

I read on other post with a similar issue ([Xamarin.Auth iOS9 Authentication SSL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745523/xamarin-auth-ios9-authentication-ssl-error))  that changing the keys on the Info.plist file would fix the issue, but this hasn't worked for me.

so far I've tried adding this to Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>    
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>     
    <dict>       
        <key>facebook.com</key>       
        <dict> 
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>   
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>         
            <true/>         
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>        
            <false/>       
        </dict>       
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>       
        <dict>  
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>         
            <true/>         
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>         
            <false/>       
        </dict>       
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>       
        <dict> 
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>         
            <true/>         
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>         
            <false/>       
        </dict>     
    </dict> 
</dict>
```

I've tried with and without "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads  "
and with and without "NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads "

I have also clean and rebuild the project multiple times, deleted safari cache from the simulator and still no luck...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add  <key>fbcdn.net</key>  as well

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro it's already there ...